$S = \{z^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 1, z > 0 \}$. Calculate $\int \int_S \frac{d \lambda_2}{z^4}$
$S = \{ z^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 1, z > 0 \}$. Calculate $\int \int_S \frac{d \lambda_2}{z^4}$.

So, first, I would change that into cylindrical coordinates, to get:

$x = rcos(\alpha)$
$y = rsin(\alpha)$
$z = z$

From the equation describing the set I get:
$$z^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 1 $$
$$z^2 = r^2cos^2(\alpha) + r^2sin^2(\alpha) + 1 $$
$$z^2 = r^2(cos^2(\alpha) + sin^2(\alpha)) + 1 $$
$$z^2 = r^2 + 1 $$
That I can put into the integral to get:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{A} \frac{1}{(r^2+1)^2} \cdot r \ dr \ d \alpha$$
But here I get stuck. How to find the upper bound for the set of values of $r$ (that is A)?

As it is stated, we can not infer what are the integration limits. Are you sure you are not missing any information?

There was $\sigma_2$ in the numerator (I changed that to $\lambda_2$) but it shouldn't change anything, right? @ÁtilaCorreia

Indeed. Notice that the surface $z = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2} + 1}$ defines a cone with vertice $(0,0,1)$.

Ok, but I am not able to bound $z$ and therefore I can't calculate the integral. Is that correct? @ÁtilaCorreia

As far as I can tell, yes. Unless that you integrate with respect to some $z_{0}\geq 1$ previously fixed.

Ok. I understand. There is nothing mentioned about fixing $z$ for any values in the problem statement, so I guess it's just an error. Well, could you recommend me any resources on integrating a cone? Or do I just google it for some insite? @ÁtilaCorreia

I have provided an example. Let me know if it is helpful.

Here is an illustrative example of cone integration.
Consider the region defined by the cone $z^{2} = x^{2} + y^{2} + 1$, the cylinder $x^{2} + y^{2} = R^{2}$ and the plane $z = 1$, where $R\geq 1$. Hence the integral to be calculated corresponds to:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-R}^{R}\int_{-\sqrt{R^{2} - x^{2}}}^{\sqrt{R^{2} - x^{2}}}
\int_{1}^{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2} + 1}}\frac{1}{z^{4}}\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}\int_{1}^{\sqrt{r^{2} + 1}}\frac{r}{(r^{2} + 1)^{2}}\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align*}

Yeah, that's great. Thank you. I can't get over that example of mine though... If it was a bit different equation. I get just $r^2 = z^2 - 1$ and that's it. As $z$ grows to $\infty$, so does $r$... but what you gonna do
